# How to track flash events using Asynchronous GA Code?

Tags: google-analytics

We have migrated Synchronous GA code to Asynchronous GA code. Now we have existing Flash files which has Synchronous GA tracking code included in ti and flash code wants pageTracker var from  Page.
Here i want to know where Page has Asyn. GA code and Flash has Syn. GA code. in this situation how to track Flash events?

Answer (score 0):

You either (listed in order of recommendation, highest to lowest):

a) update the code in your flash objects to the async version

b) write your own wrapper functions that handle all the previous calls and basically just trigger the async equivalent

c) put the sync version back on your pages, along with the async version, only remove the part of the code that tracks page views (so you don't double count)